# Not able to find quit slot, and use Q_OBJECT macro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, signals-slots, qobject

I am using VS2008 with QT 4.7.1 and add-ins. I am new to this environment.
I managed to do necessary setting and run simple "hello world". But when I try to use simple
`quit()` slot on click of a button, I failed. Also it results in build failed when trying to use `Q_OBJECT`.
After commenting `Q_OBJECT` code is built and debugged. Now it shows

**QObject::connect : no such slot QWidget::quit() in .\main.cpp found.**

below is my code

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "QtGui\QApplication"
#include "QObject"


class Notepad : public QWidget
{
    //Q_OBJECT 
public:
    Notepad();
    private slots:
        void quit();

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
}; 

Notepad::Notepad()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));
    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit() ));
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Notepad nt;// = new Notepad();
    nt.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have searched through net but failed to get reasonable solution. Most of the solution are for working with qmake on command line.
Also I am able to find .pro file for the project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see in your code your **void Notepad::quit(){}** method anywhere is it normal.

Comment: I hope so because this is not rsulting in any errors. neither do removing this affects code!!

Comment: @KaZ This was the problem. quit was'nt defined. This was not resulting direct errors but defining Q_OBJECT macro was because it couldnot find definition of quit() slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitesh: You need Q_OBJECT macro for the slots to work properly, the MOC compiles every header that contains Q_OBJECT into  moc_*****.cpp file. Add that moc*****.cpp to your project and everything should work fine. The unresolved external means that you are missing the definition of the function, did you define it anywhere?

Comment: I got the answer to posted problem. Error was due to missing definition for Notepad::quit() method. When we include Q_OBJECT macro, MOC checks for definition of all slots or signals. But if comment it, definition of quit slot is not seeked and hence no errors in that case.
Adding Definition for quit() slot solves the problem.
Thanks @blueskin

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of Notepad to a header (say, notepad.h), reenable the Q_OBJECT, then add to your .pro file:

```
HEADERS += notepad.h
```

Rerun qmake, then it should work.

Comment: I am building code through VS2008 and not using qmake.
Also I am not able to .pro file in my projecy directory.

Comment: I created a separate header file. Then recompiled after enableing Q_OBJECT.
This is the error I got.
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall Notepad::quit(void)" (?quit@Notepad@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall Notepad::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Notepad@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

Comment: Remove the header file from your project (don't delete it) and add it back again. That should trigger QT's MOC plugin and create the missing moc_notepad.h file which contains that missing symbol

Comment: Tried Tim's solution. Resulting error is :

`moc_notepad.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall Notepad::quit(void)" (?quit@Notepad@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall Notepad::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Notepad@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)`

Comment: code is working fine if I comment Q_OBJECT. Should I try out with settings for using Q_OBJECT.

Comment: Also I found that while Qobject is commented, quit() is not working in following line of code
`connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit() )); `
I am able to use close(). Also quit() is working, if change "this" to "qApp".
`connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit() ));`
Please explain this behavior.

Comment: @Nitesh qApp is another object, the global Q(Core)Application instance. The slot you connect to is the quit() method of QCoreApplication::instance, not the one of your own class.

Comment: @Nitesh: about The 4th comment (linker error): You have to implement quit(), not just declare it. I.e. add "void Notepad::quit() { ... }